# CSS styling in repeater control

Tags: css, asp.net, repeater

Hi friends i am trying to make my repeater look like the img i have attached .  I have achieved till the line Total cover but the 50% total cover line giving me headache in alignment. Can someone please guide me on this

[image]

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="TreeRepeater" runat="server" DataSourceID="TreeSource" OnItemDataBound="TreeRepeater_ItemDataBound">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div>
                                <div style="float: left; width: 15px; text-align: right;"><%# Container.ItemIndex + 1 %>.</div>
                                <div style="float: left; width: 230px; border-bottom: 1px solid black;margin-right:5px"><%# Eval("ScientificName") + ", " + Eval("CommonName")%></div>
                                <div style="float: left; width: 45px; text-align: center; border-bottom: 1px solid black; margin-right:5px"><%# string.Format("{0:0.##}",Eval("PercentageCover")) %></div>
                               <div style="float: left; width: 45px; text-align: center; border-bottom: 1px solid black; margin-right:5px; vertical-align:text-bottom"><asp:Image ID="TreeDominantImg" runat="server"  ImageUrl="~/Images/Xmark.png" Height="16px" Width="16px" Visible='<%# ((Eval("Dominant") == DBNull.Value)?(short)0:(short)Eval("Dominant")) == 1 ? true : false %>' /></div>
                                <div style="float: left; width: 45px; text-align: center; border-bottom: 1px solid black;"><%# Eval("Indicator")%></div>
                                <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <div>
                                <div style="float: left; width: 250px;"></div>
                                <div style="float: left; width: 45px; text-align: center;border-bottom: 1px solid black;"><asp:Label ID="PercentSum" runat="server"/></div>
                                <div style="float: left;"> = Total Cover</div>
                                <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <div style="display:inline-block; width: 100px;"></div> 
                                <div style="display:inline-block;width:120px;">50% of total cover:</div> 
                                <div style="display:inline-block;width:40px;border-bottom: 1px solid black;"><asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server"/></span></div>                                   
                                <div style="display:inline-block;width:120px;">20% of total cover:</div>                                    

                            </div>
                        </FooterTemplate>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post image of the current output? That would help.

Comment: HI NP3 i have added my output image

Comment: HI NP3 i have added my output image

Comment: great! Why do you have Div Style as inline-block? Did you try with having the same Style i.e. `float:left` and finally `clear:both`

Comment: still wont work the way i need..The label which has the underline is not aligning properly with the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to use `display: inline-block` rather than `float: left` because if you use `float: left`, it will exit the current flow of the element. You can change the `div` in `ItemTemplate` to this (Just copy the `style`, not the entire code)

```
<div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 15px; text-align: right;">1.</div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 230px; border-bottom: 1px solid black;margin-right:5px"></div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 45px; text-align: center; border-bottom: 1px solid black; margin-right:5px"></div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 45px; text-align: center; border-bottom: 1px solid black; margin-right:5px;"></div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 45px; text-align: center; border-bottom: 1px solid black;"></div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

and the `FooterTemplate` to this (Again just copy the `style`)

```
<div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 254px;"></div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 45px; text-align: center;border-bottom: 1px solid black;"></div>
    <div style="display: inline-block;">= Total Cover</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div style="display:inline-block; width: 44px;"></div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;width:130px;">50% of total cover:</div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;width:45px;border-bottom: 1px solid black;"></div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;width:130px;">20% of total cover:</div>    
    <div style="display:inline-block;width:45px;border-bottom: 1px solid black;"></div>
</div>
```

then it will results just like in this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyojimaru/qdoc2ks3/)

**Note**: If any of the words inside footer wrapped to a new line, just edit the `width` that you use.

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
    <FooterTemplate>
        <div>
            <div style="float: left; width: 250px;">&nbsp;</div>
            <div style="float: left; width: 45px; height:15px; text-align: center;border-bottom: 1px solid black;"><asp:Label ID="PercentSum" runat="server" Text=" "/></div>
            <div style="float: left;"> = Total Cover</div>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div style="float: left; width: 60px;">&nbsp;</div> 
            <div style="float: left;">50% of total cover:&nbsp;</div> 
            <div style="float: left; width:40px;border-bottom: 1px solid black; height:15px;text-align: center;"><asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text=" "/></span></div>
            <div style="float: left;">&nbsp;</div>
            <div style="float: left;">20% of total cover:&nbsp;</div>                                    
            <div style="float: left; width:40px;border-bottom: 1px solid black; height:15px;text-align: center;"><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=" "/></span></div>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div>
    </FooterTemplate>
```

[image: Output that I am getting]